# Android Market filter to hide app from original Droid?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an app that needs to go into the market very soon. We designed the app for Android 2.2 devices, but when we run it on the original Droid it has all kinds of problems.

The app is actually being rewritten, and the new one works fine on the Droid, but my company has decided that they want to push the original app up to the market in the mean time, as it works fine on all other devices we've tested.

My question is, are there any market filters I could apply that will hide the app from original Droid users, and if not, what set of filters would give me the smallest segment of phones that includes Droid?

I've looked over the Droid's specs, and the available filters, and I can't find anything that won't rule out 90% of the devices out there.

Comment: So it fails on the original droid when the droid has been updated to 2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen there is no way to single out specific devices on the Android Market. Since this is not an option, I recommend posting the original application up on the Android Market as is. In the release notes you can note that there is a known issue with the Motorola Droid and that it will be addressed in a future release.

If the issues with the Motorola Droid are more critical, could you explain what type of issues these are?

Comment: I've actually solved most of the issues with the droid app. The main thing was that the app is being rewritten and I didn't want to spend more time debugging the older phones.

After more investigation, I agree that a note in the description about compatibility is the best I can do for now. Thanks.

Comment: Update to this answer: it has been a while since the Android Play development console allows you to exclude a set of single devices from seeing your app. So yes, now you *can* exclude just the Droid.